# How to remove git subtree reference

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

I added a subtree via

```
git subtree add --prefix=path/to/example --squash git@github.com:johndoe/example.git master
```

and want to remove it. [There's no `git subtree rm` command.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) I already deleted all files in `path/to/example` but `path/to/example` still appears when I [list subtrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298572/770127) via

```
git log | grep git-subtree-dir | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

How can I remove the subtree *reference* from git such that it can no longer be pushed/pulled/etc.?

Answer (score 6):

Simply [remove the remote](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Removing-and-Renaming-Remotes), which is the subtree reference: `git remote rm example`

Comment: There are multiple subtree types in the wild, unfortunately.