# How to integrate remote changes before pushing to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm working with a project in a directory called `lucy` with a Git subtree called `lucy-web` (cf. [How can I list the git subtrees on the root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641057/how-can-i-list-the-git-subtrees-on-the-root)):

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git log | grep git-subtree-dir | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ":" -f2 | sort | uniq
lucy-web
```

I have two (relevant) remotes, `origin` and `staging`:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/startwithlucy/lucy.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/startwithlucy/lucy.git (push)
staging https://git.heroku.com/lucy-staging.git (fetch)
staging https://git.heroku.com/lucy-staging.git (push)
```

On `origin`, there is also a branch called `staging`:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git status
On branch staging
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/staging'.
```

In the `lucy-web` subtree, I'd like to push the contents of `origin/staging` to the `master` branch on the `staging` remote. Usually, I do that with this command, which is now yielding an error:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git push staging `git subtree split --prefix lucy-web staging`:master
cache for 09dc1ce7e3b490f30ceeabbca0c9375e2013b596 already exists!
To https://git.heroku.com/lucy-staging.git
 ! [rejected]          07fb260ddaeee35ef1c798c97dbe5e35d882bdbe -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/lucy-staging.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

It seems to me that what I need to do is merge the `master` branch on the `staging` remote into `origin/staging` before I can push, is that correct? If so, with what command can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git fetch staging master:master
git merge master
```